# Passing an array from one method to another

Tags: java, arrays, methods

i am trying to figure out how to pass the information form one method to the main method. It is probably simple and i am just missing something. please help :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String[] name =  stateName();

 public static String[] stateName() throws IOException{
   int numState =0; 
   File file = new File ("stateNames.txt");
   Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
   while (in.hasNextLine()){
      String state = in.nextLine();
       numState++;
   }
   String[] states = new String [numState];
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
   for (int i= 0; i < numState; i++){
    states[i] = reader.nextLine();
   }

   return states; 
}
```

when i go to run this, i get back: [Ljava.lang.String;@18892539 what am I doing wrong??

Comment: Go read up on the `toString()` method and how it is (not) implemented for array types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other ways to do it

```
String[] name = {"John", "Mike", "Jim"};

// this out put will be like this 
[ John, Mike, Jim ]
System.out.prinln(Arrays.asList(name));


// this way is better for formatting. Prints:
John
Mike
Jim
for (String s : name){
    System.out.println(s);     
}

// or this will print out
John Mike Jim
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, nothing is wrong. This is exactly how it is supposed to work.

When you try to print an array by using `System.out.println`, you get that weird cryptic thing that you mentioned. You can fix this by using

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(name));
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(name);
```